# How to make a loading screen with html

Tags: html, web, loading

Hi im making my website at the moment and i was wondering if there was a way to show loading screen before the whole web page appears using html is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it with with HTML only. However, it would be really simple to just use an animated .gif and the onload event in JavaScript.